# How to insert single form data into two table on single click?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

controller: Test.php

```
public function add_proposal()
{

  $roles = implode(",", $this->input->post('role'));
  $data = array(
          'admin_id' => $this->input->post('admin_id'),
          'customer_name' => $this->input->post('customer_name'),
          'purposal_name' => $this->input->post('purposal_name'),
          'duration' => $this->input->post('duration'),
          'role' => $roles, 
        );
  $this->db->insert('proposal_data',$data);
  $query = $this->db->insert('proposal',$data);
  if($query == true)
  {
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1' />";
    echo '<p style="color:green;text-align:center;">Your data save successfully</p>';
  }
  else
  {
    echo '<p style="color:red;text-align:center;">Error!</p>';
  }
}
```

view:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
      admin_id = $("#admin_id").val();
      customer_name = $("#customer_name").val();
      purposal_name = $("#purposal_name").val();
      duration = $("#duration").val();
      role = $('.test').val();
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:{"admin_id":admin_id, "customer_name":customer_name, "purposal_name":purposal_name, "duration":duration, "role":role},
        url:"<?php echo base_url('index.php/');?>test/add_proposal",
        success:function(data){
          $("#pro").html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

In this code I have a controller having name test.php. In test controller I have a function with name add_proposal where I want to insert single form data into two table on single click. Here, I am using jquery to insert my form data. If I run this code with single query then it work perfectly but in case of two query It can not work. So, How can I fix this problem ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: can you share both table structure?And is it give any error?

Comment: some column of table proposal_data are same @Jinesh

Comment: Are you sure that `proposal_data` and `proposal` have same columns?

Comment: which column different please share structure

Comment: I have more column in proposal_data but having some column as proposal tabel have.

Comment: week, years,s_date are some different column but admin_id, customer_name, purposal_name, duration, role these are the same column in proposal_data and proposal table. @Jinesh

Comment: I have find out my error. Thanks for every one for helping me. :)

Comment: What was the error?